# Upload a CSV file to a DB table in Django

Tags: python, django, csv, django-views

I am trying to develop a button that uploads a CSV that has some words in it to a DBtable through a button, the problem is that when I click the button nothing happens, I don't know if I'm missing something or I have to do it some other way. Thank you

views.py:

```
def uploadWords(request):
    up = request.POST.get('Upload') 
    if up == "Upload":
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            form = UploadFileForm()
            if request.method == "POST":
                 form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                 if form.is_valid():
                     file = request.FILES['file']
                     usr = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
                     if file.name.endswith(".csv"):
                        reader = csv.reader(file)
                        for row in reader:
                           wt = WordsTable()
                           wt.user = usr
                           wt.word1 = row[0]
                           wt.word2 = row[1]
                           wt.word3 = row[2]
                           wt.word4 = row[3]
                           wt.word5 = row[4]
                           wt.save()
                        messages.success(request, "File uploaded successfully")
                       return redirect("home")
                else:
                    messages.info(request, "File is not csv")
                    return redirect("home")
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, "base.html", context)
    else:
        return redirect("index")
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
path('login/', views.loginView, name='login'),
path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name='logout'),
path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
path('upload/', views.uploadWords, name='upload'),
]
```

base.html:

```html
<div style="text-align:center;display:block;">
   <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="file" name="upload" accept=".csv, .xlsx">
     <br>
     <button class="button btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="up" value="Upload">Upload</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding in form tag `action="{% url 'upload' %}"`

Comment: Yeah, if I do that I get: The view NLPApp.views.uploadWords didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. Do you know why? maybe the view is wrong

Comment: Yep, it looks like there is something wrong with view, but I'm not sure where you missing return

Answer (score 1):

the name of the button is "up", so you need to change

```
up = request.POST.get('up')
```